# Spring Property Editor for Date divided in three different fields

Tags: forms, spring, date, spring-mvc

I'm trying to set up a form in which user's supposed to enter his/her birthday using three different input fields (day, month, year).

What's Spring MVC's way of:

- a) prefilling those inputs when showing the form coming from a Date object.
- b) getting it from the user, validating and putting into a Date object?

EDIT:

Here's an example link to how we'd like it look: [yahoo registration](https://na.edit.yahoo.com/registration#dobFld)

Comment: @ring0 not so sure what you mean

Comment: misread your question - please ignore comment

Answer (score 0):

In spring mvc, for the default, it can't automatically convert the object as this date to a Date type object, so you just get the string in controller, so before get/post the request to server, you should combine these year, month, day together. In controller, you convert the string to Date with java. and it's the same that the controller should return a string, then in the page, you can use js to split it. But I recommend you choose a datepicker plugin, it will be better and save a lot of work.

Answer (score -1):

Hey @user1241320 you can do format his/her birthday from view tier with calendar of any one javascript framework, for example, `JQuery`.

I hopes these helps :)